# Doctrine : query not happening with where clause

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder, symfony3.x

I don't understand my mistake here,
I'm doing a doctrine query in Symfony, which is supposed to find results from a search and order them at the same time.

When checking the page, I get no results and the query isn't in the profiler.
If I only use order by, I get a result and the query in profiler.

Here's my query :

```
public function getVehiclesbySearchAndSort($sort, $search)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('v')
    ->where('v.model like :re')//commenting these lines makes the sorting query happen
    ->setParameter('re', $search)//but with the where clause, no query is happening
    ->orderBy('v.price', $sort)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
    ;

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: What is `v.model` type and what is the content of `$search` ?

Comment: v.model is a string and search is anything the user would type, so if the user types something that isn't a model in the database, no result is normal. Just figured it out though(even though I didn't understand why it wasn't in profiler) so I'll mark it as resolved

Comment: `->setParameter('re', '%' . $search . '%')`

Comment: Precisely…thanks ! haha.

Answer (score 0):

While I still didn't figure why I wasn't getting the query in the profiler, it was in the logs.

Now for the dummy mistake :
I forgot to use the '%' to wrap around the like input, as Cid figured too.

```
->setParameter('re', '%' . $search . '%')
```